# VideoJS - Pause streaming media for video elements not in focus

Tags: javascript, video.js

Is it possible to force VideoJS to stop streaming videos that no longer have the main focus on a page or that have been paused? If, for example, I load two videos and then decide to make one of them fullscreen so the other loses focus or if I switch tab and both lose focus I'd like to not only pause the video from playing but prevent the player continuing to download ( via xhr ) the video stream.

It is simple to call the `play` and `pause` methods when needed but I have yet to figure a way that this streaming might also be paused - can anyone suggest how this might be done. I have toyed with removing the video `src` attribute having seen mention of that somewhere but that results in several errors and did not resolve the problem.

Initially I was using the HLS code ( `videojs-contrib-hls.js` ) but read somewhere that it might be better using the http streaming code ( `videojs-http-streaming.js` ) ~ same results.

When playing with the [videojs streaming test page](https://videojs.github.io/http-streaming/) the default playlist doesn't exhibit this behaviour but other playlists do cause this downloading behaviour.

The code below is a pseudo facsimile of the real code but works as it stands to reproduce the errors. When either video is maximised &/or both videos are paused you can observe network requests in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Stop VideoJS buffering other videos that do not have focus</title>
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;}
            div.container{ width:600px; height:400px; margin:1rem; display:inline-block;clear:none; padding:0; }
            video{max-width:600px;max-height:400px;opacity:1}
            [type='button'].play{ width:100%; padding:1rem; margin:auto; float:none; position:relative; top:130px; }
            [type='button'][name='ctrl']{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
        </style>
        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.7.1/video.min.js'></script>
        <script src='//unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js'></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                let urls=[
                    'https://edge1.dashmedia.tv/onestudio/gonefishing/playlist.m3u8?fluxustv.m3u8',
                    'https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8'
                ];


                let players={};
                let videos={};


                const maximise=function(e){
                    let player=players[ this.previousElementSibling.id ];
                        player.requestFullscreen();             
                };


                /* 
                    For any video currently playing that is NOT fullscreen 
                    or not visible ( calculated by IntersectionObserver not shown here )
                    should be paused and the network stream should be stopped
                    for the duration. How?

                    The methods below cause errors. Simply using `player.pause()` will
                    happily pause the video but it will continue to stream the file
                    and so causing excessive network usage for hidden items.
                */
                document.addEventListener( 'fullscreenchange', event=>{
                    let player;
                    let video;

                    const isFullscreen=function(){
                        return document.fullscreenElement!==null;
                    };

                    Object.keys( videos ).map( id =>{
                        player=players[ id ];
                        video=videos[ id ];
                        if( video && video != event.target.querySelector('video') ){
                            if( isFullscreen() )player.pause();
                            else player.play();
                        }
                        console.info('%cPlayer:%s Paused:%s','color:yellow;background:fuchsia;',id,player.paused());
                    });
                });



                /* event listener to play/stop videos */
                document.querySelector('input[name="ctrl"]').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    urls.forEach( ( url, index )=>{
                        let id='player_'+index;

                        let oCont=document.createElement('div');
                            oCont.className='container';

                        let oVideo=document.createElement('video');
                            oVideo.id=id;
                            oVideo.width=600;
                            oVideo.width=400;

                        let oBttn=document.createElement('input');
                            oBttn.className='play';
                            oBttn.type='button';
                            oBttn.value='Maximise';
                            oBttn.onclick=maximise;

                        oCont.appendChild( oVideo );
                        oCont.appendChild( oBttn );
                        document.body.appendChild( oCont );


                        let video_options={ 
                            'controls':true,
                            'autoplay':true,
                            'preload':'auto',
                            'muted':true,
                            children:[]
                        };
                        let video=window.player = videojs( id, video_options );
                            video.src({ src:url, type:'application/x-mpegURL' } );
                            video.ready( ()=>{
                                video.name=id;
                                video.errorDisplay=false;
                                video.play();
                            });
                            video.on('error',function(e){
                                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                console.info( '%cError:%s\nCode:%s', 'background:lime;color:black;', this.error().message, this.error().code )
                                video.dispose();
                            })

                        players[ id ]=video;
                        videos[ id ]=oVideo;
                    });//end forEach
                });//end play click handler
            });//end listener
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='button' name='ctrl' value='Play videos' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @JCraine - sadly no!